# writing Qt3D application in windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, qt4, qt3d

I am going to write Qt3D application in windows.
I have also installed necessary tools , but after compilation i receive 'unresolved external symbol' error. what is the solution?

Note : my compiler is microsoft visual c++ 9.0

Comment: Do you have some code we could look at?

Comment: Seems like you're not using Qt .pro files?

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking-in the Qt3D library? If you don't - that's the reason for your issue. Open your project and add the neccessary .lib file into the list of libraries (and don't forget to either use a full, preferably relative, path or to add additional library path to the project's library path list)

Comment: I added Qt3D.lib and QtOpenGL4.lib but still have some errors. in fact before adding these .lib files number of errors was 30 and after adding it dropped to 3

Comment: It seems all necessary files have been added!